# jquery script to extract src from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to extract the src of the iframe which are present in a html page and save those in a file. I wanted to use jquery for doing this. Is it possible to write a jquery . Which one of php /javascript /jquery should I use for this.

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 1):

First retrieve the source of each iframe element on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("iframe").each(function() {
        //You'll want to persist this value somewhere instead of alerting it.
        alert($(this).attr("src"));
    });
});
```

Once you have the iframe source(s), it's up to you how to submit them to the server. You could persist the value(s) in a hidden element in the form or use the `.ajax()` method of jQuery to post the form via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks its working but can it be added as a plugin? So this shd be done whenever the page is loaded.

Comment: @vinay, You don't need to make this a plugin to execute it when the page loads. Simply add it to the `$(document).ready()` event handler. See above edits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   var ifrms = [];
   $("iframe").each(function() {
      ifmrs.push(this.src);
   });

   $.ajax(function(){
     url: "urlOfThePage",
     data: { sources: ifmrs }
   });
```

Comment: What shd I replace the urlofthepage with ? If I need to save the data in a remote server.

Comment: I have one more question --- after we write a jquery function and save it as .js file,how to install it in a browser as a plugin.. can we do that

Comment: Yes, you have to create a page which will save the data into remote server and specify that page name in the url. If you dont need to make it as plugin then you need to include this code into a common js file which will be used across all the pages in your application.